# Visual Studio not showing Intellisense for external library

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

I use an external library (itextsharp) which i downloaded through nuget. the version i use is 5.5.8. Intellisense is not showing the documentation for this library.

Initially, I thought that this library didn't ship with proper XML documentation.

However I later found out that it did come with a proper XML documentation file.

How to get Visual Studio to recognize the documention and show it in Intellisense?

I found out that the xml filename doesn't math the dll case, but changing it didn't yield any improvement?